# playsms with gammu is not sending sms messages

Tags: sms-gateway

playsms with gammu gateway is not sending sms.

/var/log/gammu/smsd.log :

> gammu-smsd[25994]: Starting phone communication...
>
> gammu-smsd[25994]: **Error at init connection: Can not open specified file.** **(CANTOPENFILE[28])**
>
> gammu-smsd[25994]: Going to 30 seconds sleep because of too much connection errors

but gammu is sending sms by this command

> echo "sms test" | /usr/bin/gammu --sendsms TEXT ######

gammu-smsd configuration file:

> # /etc/gammu-smsdrc
>
> [gammu]
>
> port = /dev/ttyUSB1
>
> connection = at115200
>
> logfile = /var/log/gammu/gammu.log
>
> logformat = textall
>
> [smsd]
>
> Service = files
>
> InboxPath = /var/spool/gammu/inbox/
>
> OutboxPath = /var/spool/gammu/outbox/
>
> SentSMSPath = /var/spool/gammu/sent/
>
> ErrorSMSPath = /var/spool/gammu/error/
>
> InboxFormat = unicode
>
> OutboxFormat = unicode
>
> TransmitFormat = auto
>
> debugLevel = 1
>
> LogFile = /var/log/gammu/smsd.log
>
> DeliveryReport = sms
>
> DeliveryReportDelay = 7200
>
> CheckSecurity = 0

also *gammu-smsd-inject* is not working

> echo "All your base are belong to us" | gammu-smsd-inject TEXT ####
>   output of this command:
>
> > -smsd-inject[19831]: Using FILES service
>
> -smsd-inject[19831]: Configuring
>
> SMSD...
>
> -smsd-inject[19831]: SHM token: 0xffffffffce00170a (-838854902)
>
> -smsd-inject[19831]: Warning: No PIN code in /etc/
>
> -smsdrc file
>
> -smsd-inject[19831]: CommTimeout=30, SendTimeout=30, ReceiveFrequency=0, ResetFrequency=0, HardResetFrequency=0
>
> -smsd-inject[19831]: checks: CheckSecurity=0, CheckBattery=1, CheckSignal=1
>
> -smsd-inject[19831]: mode: Send=1, Receive=1
>
> -smsd-inject[19831]: deliveryreport = sms
>
> -smsd-inject[19831]: phoneid =
>
> -smsd-inject[19831]: Inbox is "/var/spool/
>
> /inbox/" with format "unicode"
>
> -smsd-inject[19831]: Outbox is "/var/spool/
>
> /outbox/" with format "unicode" and transmission format "auto"
>
> -smsd-inject[19831]: Sent SMS moved to "/var/spool/
>
> /sent/"
>
> -smsd-inject[19831]: SMS with errors moved to "/var/spool/
>
> /error/"
>
> -smsd-inject[19831]: Created outbox message OUTC20140315_122347_00_sms0.txt
>   Written message with ID /var/spool/
>
> /outbox/OUTC20140315_122347_00_sms0.txt

Any idea why the sms messages are not being sent?